# Lambda Illegal start of expression in BlueJ

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, bluej

I am currently learning along with "Java in Easy Steps 5th Edition" http://ineasysteps.com/products-page/all_books/java-in-easy-steps-5th-edition-covers-java-8/

However, I have just encountered an "Illegal start of expression" using BlueJ, which is highlighting my Lambda expression. I would normally reference against the source code for the book, but this isn't available online yet.

Can anyone help me out?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Lists
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Alpha");
        list.add("Delta");
        list.add("Charlie");
        System.out.println("List: " + list);

        System.out.println("Replacing: " + list.get(1) + "\n");
        list.set(1, "Bravo");

        list.forEach((x) -> System.out.println("Item: " + x));
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I have updated the code so it works, eliminating the lambda expression:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Lists
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Alpha");
        list.add("Delta");
        list.add("Charlie");
        System.out.println("List: " + list);

        System.out.println("Replacing: " + list.get(1) + "\n");
        list.set(1, "Bravo");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        System.out.println("Item: " + list.get(i));
    }
}
```

But it would still be great if I knew why there was an error. Cheers

Comment: Are you sure BlueJ supports Java 8?

Comment: In all honesty, no, I don't have a clue...

Comment: well, as it is not mentioned here http://www.bluej.org/versions.html it most likely is not supported.

Comment: Thanks, I have concluded that it does not support Java 8. (Currently)

Comment: Still doesn't support it! Haha

Edit: in the BlueJ versions site it says it supports Java 8, but I'm getting this same error message and for the same reason too.